# Assigning object side label on multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am considering a geometrical problems where objects, called here `Thing`(mostly rectangles) are split into smaller rectangles. In my dataframe, I have two columns `s1` and `s2`:

```
Thing  s1  s2  id1  id2
0      A   2   4    0    1
1      A   2   4    1    2
2      A   2   4    1    3
3      A   2   4    0    4
4      B   6   2    1    1
5      B   6   2    2    0
6      B   6   2    3    0
7      B   6   2    4    1
8      B   6   2    5    1
9      B   6   2    6    0
10     C   6   2    1    4
11     C   3  10    2    0
12     C   3  10    3    6
13     C   3  10    4   67
14     C   3  10    5    0
15     C   3  10    5    3
16     C   3  10    6    4
17     C   3  10    6    4
18     C   3  10    6    3
19     C   3  10    6    3
```

**Explanation** :
If you take `Thing` A, the column `s1` has value 2. This means that A is a rectangle (The same is true of `Thing` B due to the 2 in column `s2`. Any Thing with a 2 in either column `s1` or `s2` is a rectangle. All others are not.

For `Thing` A, the column `id1` is eith 0 or 1, indicating which side of the rectangle I am on. For A, the other, `id2`, is only a cumcount of the splits.

Now, what I want is a way to create a column `Side` That labels the side of every single rectangle in my dataframe. The output I desire is the following:

```
Thing  s1  s2  id1  id2 Side
0      A   2   4    0    1   S1
1      A   2   4    1    2   S2
2      A   2   4    1    3   S2
3      A   2   4    0    4   S1
4      B   6   2    1    1   S2
5      B   6   2    2    0   S1
6      B   6   2    3    0   S1
7      B   6   2    4    1   S2
8      B   6   2    5    1   S2
9      B   6   2    6    0   S1
10     C   6   2    1    4  NaN
11     C   3  10    2    0  NaN
12     C   3  10    3    6  NaN
13     C   3  10    4   67  NaN
14     C   3  10    5    0  NaN
15     C   3  10    5    3  NaN
16     C   3  10    6    4  NaN
17     C   3  10    6    4  NaN
18     C   3  10    6    3  NaN
19     C   3  10    6    3  NaN
```

I tried, the following but it just didn't work:

```
rf = []
for thing in Objects:
    df = Named[Named['Thing']=='{}'.format(thing)]
    if(df.s1==2):
        df = df.assign(Side =np.where(df.id1 == 0, 'S1','S2'))
    if(df.s2==2):
        df = df.assign(Side = np.where(df.id2 == 0, 'S1', 'S2'))
    else:
        df = df.assign(Side = np.where((df.id1>1)|(df.id2>1), np.nan,np.nan)
     rt.append(df)
```

and

```
Named = Named.assign(Side = np.where((Named.s1 ==2) & (Named.id1 == 0),'S1', np.where((Named.s1 ==2) & (Named.id1 == 1),'S2',
                                             np.where((Named.s2 ==2) & (Named.id2 == 0),'S1', np.where((Named.s2 ==2) & (Named.id2 == 1),'S2',
                                             np.where((Named.s1 !=2) | (Named.s2 != 2),np.nan),np.nan),np.nan),np.nan),np.nan)
```

Now, replacing 0 by `S1` and 1 by `S2` simply doesn't work because 0 could very show up in  the `id1` and `id2` columns for non-rectangular obejcts.

I am grateful for any help on doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with multiple `np.where` and also `groupby`:

```
>>> Named['Side'] = np.where(Named.filter(regex=r's\d').eq(2).any(1).groupby(Named['Thing']).transform(all), np.where(np.where(Named['s2'].eq(2), Named['id2'], Named['id1']), 'S2', 'S1'), np.nan)
>>> Named
   Thing  s1  s2  id1  id2 Side
0      A   2   4    0    1   S1
1      A   2   4    1    2   S2
2      A   2   4    1    3   S2
3      A   2   4    0    4   S1
4      B   6   2    1    1   S2
5      B   6   2    2    0   S1
6      B   6   2    3    0   S1
7      B   6   2    4    1   S2
8      B   6   2    5    1   S2
9      B   6   2    6    0   S1
10     C   6   2    1    4  nan
11     C   3  10    2    0  nan
12     C   3  10    3    6  nan
13     C   3  10    4   67  nan
14     C   3  10    5    0  nan
15     C   3  10    5    3  nan
16     C   3  10    6    4  nan
17     C   3  10    6    4  nan
18     C   3  10    6    3  nan
19     C   3  10    6    3  nan
>>>
```